# Configuring Grub2 on a second raid 1 hard drive on Fedora

Tags: fedora, raid, rpm

Im trying to reconfigure grub to install on both /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, but the only command I have been able to find is dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc, which isnt really helpful since I am using rpm. Is there any way to reconfigure this using rpm? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the CentOS guide: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SoftwareRAIDonCentOS5

```
# /sbin/grub
grub> device (hd0) /dev/sda
grub> device (hd1) /dev/sdb
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0)
grub> root (hd1,0)
grub> setup (hd1)
grub> quit
```

You might also find `find /grub/stage1` useful.